# Is there a cleaner way to write the code for conditional replacement of outlier values with the group mean in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the DF below - in the Value Column, Product 3(i.e, 100) and Product 4 (i.e. 98) have amounts that are outliers. I want to

1. group by ['Class']
2. obtain the mean of the [Value] excluding the outlier amount
3. replace the outlier amount with the mean calculated in step 2.

Any suggestions of how to structure the code greatly appreciated. I have my code that works given the sample table, but I have a feeling that when I implement in the real solution it might not work.

```
 Product,Class,Value
0   1   A   5
1   2   A   4
2   3   A   100
3   4   B   98
4   5   B   20
5   6   B   25
```

My code implementation:

```
# Establish the condition to remove the outlier rows from the DF
stds = 1.0 
filtered_df = df[~df.groupby('Class')['Value'].transform(lambda x: abs((x-x.mean()) / x.std()) > stds)]
```

Output:

```
Product Class   Value
0   1   A   5
1   2   A   4
4   5   B   20
5   6   B   25
```

```
# compute mean of each class without the outliers
class_means = filtered_df[['Class', 'Value']].groupby(['Class'])['Value'].mean()
```

Output:

```
Class 
A     4.5
B    22.5
```

```
#extract rows in DF that are outliers and fail the test
outlier_df = df[df.groupby('Class')['Value'].transform(lambda x: abs((x-x.mean()) / x.std()) > stds)]
outlier_df
```

Output:

```
Product Class   Value
2   3   A   100
3   4   B   98
```

```
#replace outlier values with computed means grouped by class
outlier_df['Value'] = np.where((outlier_df.Class == class_means.index), class_means,outlier_df.Value)
outlier_df
```

Output:

```
    Product Class   Value
2   3   A   4.5
3   4   B   22.5
```

```
#recombine cleaned dataframes
df_cleaned = pd.concat([filtered_df,outlier_df], axis=0 )
df_cleaned
```

Output:

```
Product Class   Value
0   1   A   5.0
1   2   A   4.0
4   5   B   20.0
5   6   B   25.0
2   3   A   4.5
3   4   B   22.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as follows:

1. Start from your code:

   ```
   stds = 1.0
   ```
2. Save your lambda function under a variable:

   ```
   isOutlier = lambda x: abs((x - x.mean()) / x.std()) > stds
   ```
3. Define the following function, to be applied to each group:

   ```
   def newValue(grp):
       val = grp.Value
       outl = isOutlier(val)
       return val.mask(outl, val[~outl].mean())
   ```
4. Generate new *Value* column:

   ```
    df.Value = df.groupby('Class', group_keys=False).apply(newValue)
   ```

The result is:

```
   Product Class  Value
0        1     A    5.0
1        2     A    4.0
2        3     A    4.5
3        4     B   22.5
4        5     B   20.0
5        6     B   25.0
```

You even don't lose the original row order.

## Edit

Or you can "incorporate" the content of your lambda function in *newValue*
(as you don't call it in any other place):

```
def newValue(grp):
    val = grp.Value
    outl = abs((val - val.mean()) / val.std()) > stds
    return val.mask(outl, val[~outl].mean())
```